# Existing query optimization

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, view, query-optimization

We have 5 tables and we are trying to create a view to get the results.

Below is the view which is working fine.

I need suggestions. Is it a good practice to write this query in this way or it can be optimized in a better way.

```
SELECT p.Pid,  hc.hcid, hc.Accomodation, ghc.ghcid, ghc.ProductFeatures,   wp.existing, wp.acute, mc.cardiaccover, mc.cardiaclimitationperiod
FROM   TableA p 
      LEFT JOIN TableB hc 
             ON p.pid = hc.pid 
      LEFT JOIN TableC ghc 
             ON p.pid = ghc.pid 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                 FROM   (SELECT hcid, 
                                title, 
                                wperiodvalue + '-' + CASE WHEN 
                                wperiodvalue > 1 THEN 
                                unit + 
                                        's' ELSE 
                                unit END wperiod 
                         FROM   TableD) d 
                        PIVOT ( Max(wperiod) 
                              FOR title IN (acute, 
                                            existing 
                                           ) ) piv1) wp 
             ON hc.hcid = wp.hcid 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT * 
                 FROM   (SELECT hcid, 
                                title + col new_col, 
                                value 
                         FROM   TableE 
                                CROSS apply ( VALUES (cover, 
                                            'Cover'), 
                                                     (Cast(limitationperiod AS 
                                                           VARCHAR 
                                                           (10)), 
                                            'LimitationPeriod') ) x (value, col 
                                            )) d 
                        PIVOT ( Max(value) 
                              FOR new_col IN (cardiaccover, 
                                              cardiaclimitationperiod, 
                                              cataracteyelenscover, 
                                              cataracteyelenslimitationperiod
                                             ) ) piv2) mc 
             ON hc.hcid = mc.hcid
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Different dbms products optimize differently.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to break down the query using temporary table, create stored procedure then dump data in the one new table and with the help of that table you can create view:

Store both PIVOT result in tow seperate temp tables as

```
SELECT * INTO #pvtInfo FROM (  --first PIVOT query
SELECT * INTO #pvtInfoTwo FROM (  --second PIVOT query
```

Then your final query will be as :

```
SELECT p.Pid,  
    hc.hcid, 
    hc.Accomodation, 
    ghc.ghcid, 
    ghc.ProductFeatures,   
    wp.existing, 
    wp.acute, 
    mc.cardiaccover, 
    mc.cardiaclimitationperiod
FROM TableA p 
LEFT JOIN TableB hc ON p.pid = hc.pid 
LEFT JOIN TableC ghc ON p.pid = ghc.pid 
LEFT JOIN #pvtInfo wp ON hc.hcid = wp.hcid 
LEFT JOIN #pvtInfoTwo mc ON hc.hcid = mc.hcid
```

First you can try then only go with SP and VIEW.

Hope, It will help.